# How to validate a boolean in Struts 2 Validation Framework

Tags: validation, struts2, expression

Simple: I have to be sure the privacy checkbox on my form is checked. I tryed to use the expression validator (and the fieldexpression validator) but it does'n work.
Can anobody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information? How were you using the expression validator, and why didn't it work? Seems like that approach should work fine.

A few things to consider: do you have both a "getter" and a "setter" method for your boolean? Do you have both the "validation" and the "workflow" interceptors in your interceptor stack (the "defaultStack" does, for example).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<field name="agreeToPrivacy">
    <field-validator type="expression" >  
    <param name="expression">agreeToPrivacy == true</param>  
            <message>You must agree to the privacy agreement to continue.</message>  
    </field-validator>
</field>
```